# MEncoder install issue

Tags: linux, software-installation, mplayer

I'm looking for a simple install guide for `mencoder` on a linux server via SSH.

Every guide I've come to so far links me to out of date versions.

Comment: @Ben: You need to specify what distro and version you are using in order to get relevant answers.

Answer (score 1):

If your distribution has a package manager (most do nowadays), simply use that. It can be part  of the 'mplayer' package, or it has its own package

On Debian this would be (see comments):

```
sudo apt-get install mencoder
```

If you are not root or don't have a package manager, download the source from http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/dload.html and install it like a regular program, probably something like:

```
./configure
make
```

Comment: mencoder is not included with mplayer on debian due to licensing issues. so you'd have to build from source.

Comment: On Debian, use the [Debian Multimedia repository](http://www.debian-multimedia.org/). On Ubuntu, use the [Medibuntu repository](http://www.medibuntu.org/).

Comment: sorry, you're right. I update the post.